# jQuery namespacing global variable

Tags: jquery, namespaces

Am quite new to namespacing etc so hopefully this will be straightforward.

I have a variable in a jQuery hover function that needs to be made available to the global space.

To namespace my global variables i placed this code in a JS file that occurs before any other JS code:

```
$(function() {

    // Namespace
    jQuery.icisBoard = {};

});
```

I then have a tooltip function that occurs after this in a seperate JS file:

```
// Tooltip function
$(function() {

    $('.w_market_updates ul li a:contains("...")').addClass('tip_holder');

    $(".tip_holder").hover(function() {

        var $containerWidth = $(this).width();

        var $offset = $(this).offset();

        $.icisBoard.$thisTitle = $(this).attr('title');

        $('#icis_dashboard').prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $thisTitle + '</div>');

        $(this).attr('title', '')        

        var $tipWidth = $('#tooltip').width();

        var $tipHeight = $('#tooltip').height();

        $('#tooltip').css({
            'display': 'block',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': $offset.top - ($tipHeight + 5),
            'left': $offset.left - ($tipWidth - $containerWidth) / 2
        });

    }, function() {

        $('#tooltip').remove();

        $(this).attr('title', $.icisBoard.$thisTitle) 

    });


});
```

This does not appear to work for me as know the hover functionality does not work.  I am getting the scope all wrong?  I am not even sure that the variable is available to the global scope anyway in this instance and if i just have `$thisTitle` instead of `$.icisBoard.$thisTitle` the functionality works.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No.

it is strange because if i declare the variable with 'var' prefix it does not seem to be available to the hover out part of the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$('#icis_dashboard').prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $thisTitle + '</div>');
```

to

```
$('#icis_dashboard').prepend('<div id="tooltip">' + $.icisBoard.$thisTitle + '</div>');
```

You don't have a variable `$thisTitle`.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/qna7W/

(*I changed it a bit, otherwise the tooltip would not have been in the view*)

Comment: Thanks.

Sorry my eyes glazed over that one.

Is there any way to extend the global object.  For example if i wanted to have multiple global variables under the Tooltip function e.g.

$.icisBoard.tooltip.$thisTitle

Comment: @RyanP13: Sure, you just have to assign an object to `$.icisBoard.tooltip`, i.e. `$.icisBoard.tooltip = {}`. One further note: You don't *have to* add this "namespace" to the jQuery object. You could just create a global variable `icisBoard`.